# AES Crypt version 2 issue

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I am looking into using a file encryption library in python: pyAesCrypt

The github page states the following for the library:

```
IMPORTANT SECURITY NOTE: version 2 of the AES Crypt file format does not authenticate the 
"file size modulo 16" byte. 
This implies that an attacker with write access to the encrypted file 
may alter the corresponding plaintext file size by up to 15 bytes.
```

I think this means 15 bytes can be added to the encrypted file which on decryption means that data could end in the decrypted file post decryption but i am not 100%?

Can someone with more experience in this area explain this to me in layman's terms if this is an incorrect assumption?

Thanks

Comment: I don't directly see it in the source, but I only see #2 code, one author, no scheme description or design, spurious HMAC & encryption keys, little activity and indeed a bug that is on the home page and not in the issues. Why would you use a library that's got no description and little to no support for a security relevant application, no less? There is a crapton of these libraries around by persons that just learned crypto and see some need to spawn such libraries, very few can be trusted to get it right. Use one that has seen some support / review

Comment: Thanks @Maarten-reinstateMonica as said i am looking into it and pondered on the statement, feel free to make a good suggestion for a library of which you have experience with in django and i will add it to my list to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this library and read this information.

The file size is only an information, which is needed to check if the decrypted file is the same as the encrypted. If the check has a different result, something happened during decryption and you have a corrupt file.

Changing this information does not affect the content of the encrypted or decrypted file if the encryption and decryption is implemented correctly.

While it's correct, that the file size can be changed. I think the attack vector is wrong.

> This implies that an attacker with write access to the encrypted file
> may alter the corresponding plaintext file size by up to 15 bytes.

Filesize modulo 16 means the remainder will be stored.

A file with a size of 64 bytes and a file with 128 bytes have the same remainder which is 0.

If you have a file with 72 bytes, you have a remainder of 8. To get the same remainder you can alter the plain text file to 56 bytes (72-16), 88 (72+16).

Those files will create the same meta information when encrypted again.

I have looked at the source code and this package only parses and writes the [AES Crypt File format](https://www.aescrypt.com/aes_file_format.html). The encryption itself is done with the [python cryptography package](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/), which is well known and tested.

Note: I have not done a full source code audit and I'm not a cryptography expert, but the [source code of pyAesCrypt](https://github.com/marcobellaccini/pyAesCrypt/blob/master/pyAesCrypt/crypto.py) seems to be fine.